# wrong directionality in minted environment

Tags: lyx, minted

I write a document in Lyx and use a minted environment. I added a python code inside a Tex code box, but after compilation, Lyx "reverses" the order of the words inside the " " marks.

This is the code I wrote:

```
\begin{minted}[linenos=true, numbersep=5pt, fontsize=\small]{python}
Total = 0
I = 0
while I < 100:
    x = int(input("enter a number"))
    if x < 0:
        continue
    Total += x
    I += 1
print(Total)
\end{minted}
```

and this is the result after compilation:
[image]

as you can see, the order is reversed. I tried "playing" with the order, to "trick" Lyx to reverse it again, but it's still not perfect.

how can I solve this?

Comment: Try adding `\begin{LTR}` before `\begin{minted}`, and `\end{LTR}` after `\end{minted}`. Usually LyX do it by default if you use the minted environment from the GUI and don't use ERT, but if IRCC you use the latter.

Comment: worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: you’re welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Udi suggested in the comments

> Try adding `\begin{LTR}` before `\begin{minted}`, and `\end{LTR}` after `\end{minted}`. Usually, LyX does it by default if you use the minted environment from the GUI and don't use ERT, but if IRCC you use the latter.

Comment: You can accept your own answer.

Comment: apparently only after 2 days. But I hope whoever encounters this problem in the future, will see your answer. Thanks again!